# Webpage isn't rendering pictures added using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add an image to a website using Javascript. I am doing this using createElement, and setAttribute to point to the image in my file directory. Here is the very basic code:

```
var lambda = document.createElement("img");
lambda.setAttribute("src", "img/512.png");
var body = document.querySelector("body");
body.prepend(lambda);
```

I am confused because when the website loads, the image does not render properly. However, when I inspect the broken image and copy/paste the html from my browser into my html document and then reload, the image loads properly. My question is, why is the browser unable to load the image when I call it using Javascript, but it works perfectly when the code generated by Javascript is copied into the html document?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/img/512.png`?

Comment: Your code works if you use the correct path to the image. Perhaps you have a base href?

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: @WaisKamal Where is any jQuery in this code? It is Vanilla JS

Comment: here is your error: `var body = document.querySelector("body")`  you are selecting an invalid element. it needs to be in an id or a class.

Comment: @CodeCreate No, it doesn't. That line works fine.

Comment: Isn't prepend() a jquery method?!

Comment: @WaisKamal No, [it isn't](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend).

Comment: I am using vanilla js. I have also tried /img/512.png, which is correct relative to where my html file is located, and ../img/512.png, which is the path from my js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to see what is going on, and then look in the network tab to see what is loaded

```js
const imgSrc = "img/512.png"; // "https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-512-thumb/lambda-2-550999.png"; 
const lambda = document.createElement("img");
lambda.onload = function() {document.querySelector("body").prepend(lambda)}
lambda.onerror = function(err) { console.log(err,err.path) }
lambda.setAttribute("src",imgSrc);
```

For example for your image URL I get this in the network console

```
Request URL: https://stacksnippets.net/img/512.png
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
```